# Additional digits after decimal points

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, floating-point

Select Query giving additional digits after decimal point.
The datatype of the column is decimal(4,2).
The value stored is 1.39 but what i get is 1.3899999999999999.

I can perform round,number_format in php but Is there a way to get the exact value without extra digits after decimal ??

Database is MSSQL.

Comment: Target variable data type?

Comment: I am using php5.6 ...so no explicit datatype is specified..

Comment: SELECT ROUND(1.3899999999999999, 2)

Comment: Try `cast(column as char(6))`, or whatever fits php best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably your database library is converting the `DECIMAL(4, 2)` datatype to a `float` behind the scenes. Now `1.39` cannot be expressed exactly as a floating point number, instead it is approximated to `1.3899999999999999023003738329862244427204132080078125` (use an [online converter](http://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/) or do a `<?php ini_set("precision", 99); var_dump(1.39);`).

There are some workarounds, the simplest one is to convert the decimal number to string at the query level:

```
SELECT CAST(col AS VARCHAR(4)) AS col_as_string FROM ...
```

The other solution is to use the [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function which seems to round the values.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware the PHP has no precise data type for numbers with decimal places. When working with such numbers it will always use an approximite data type (floating point numbers).

So comparing 0.1 + 0.2 with 0.3 for instance may very likely result in `false`. That means: be careful with equality comparisions.

When displaying such values you should never rely on the default presentation, but use `number_format` instead. E.g. `number_format($value, 2)`.

If you want to avoid floating point issues completely, then don't use numbers with decimal places. That can be a hassle though (e.g. retrieving the integer 139 for 1.39 and keeping in mind that this value means hundredths).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect 1.39 can't be exactly represented as a float.

I don't know PHP, so here is some Java code to demonstrate:

```
class DoubleFloat {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    float f = 1.39f;
    double d = 1.39f;
    System.out.println("f = " + f);
    System.out.println("d = " + d);
  }
}
```

The output:

```
f = 1.39
d = 1.3899999856948853
```

Depends what you are trying to do on the PHP side, but you could store the number as an integer, e.g. 1.39 is stored as 139 and convert it *somehow* on the PHP side.